# How to get Remote User Credentials in TwinCAT XAE of Target System?

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

How can I get the password for the Remote User Credentials in TwinCAT XAE.

*Context:*

I have TwinCAT XAE in development PC-Windows and I have TwinCAT XAR on another PC-WINDOWS which is my Runtime PC. I want to connect both these PCs via Ethernet/IP to shift my code from development PC to my Runtime PC.

I have done the TCP and UDP settings for the runtime PC already.

The Development PC is detecting the run time PC in the select target/System window. But, I am un able to connect them because I don't know the password of the remote user for the remote user credentials window. I have tried the password of the runtime PC (which a PC asks when it starts) and also the default value 1, as mentioned in some of the online videos[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG6sP.jpg)

Comment: Hi MAK, welcome to StackOverflow. Your image doesn't show currently, You should add the ! before the [] to show it. See for more info the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: The [default password is indeed 1](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/sw_os/2019798923.html?id=5873364939697289117). If that doesn't work it has been changed. I think the only option then would be to reset the PLC to it's default factory settings. I'm not sure if Beckhoff installed something to do this, or you need to reset Windows entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the credentials for an administrator account on the PC. The default username/password of "Administrator/1" only applies to factory default Beckhoff PLCs, and not your Windows PC that you have created yourself. To solve this issue, simply create an account called "Administrator" on the Windows 10 PC running the XAR and set a password of 1.